# What happens when someone edits your answer to the point where you can't even recognize it?

Tags: discussion, edits

There is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26339049/routing-to-a-fixed-url-in-asp-net-mvc) where I gave a simple solution that looked like this:

[image]

I came back to the question and my answer has been totally rewritten to the point where 90% of the text isn't mine and where the entire code is different! It's not my answer anymore. I don't think that's how edits should work.

[image]

What do we do when something like this happens and how do we prevent it from happening in the first place?

Comment: Apparently the [review queue accepted that edit from a 13-rep user](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5984834). The 12k user just made it bearable to read. (It shouldn't have been accepted.)

Comment: Looks like the OP is the one who edited the answer.

Comment: Heh, indeed. That's curious o.O

Comment: @Cerbrus: In editing that reviewer was the *sole reviewer to approve the edit*. I'm am rather puzzled as to why that reviewer did this in the first place.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The reviewer probably didn't pay attention to the "before" state of the answer. He probably only saw a result that lacked formatting.

Comment: As an aside, the OP went to ask another question with the edit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341211/routing-in-asp-net-mvc4 Not sure why because the one-line answer works just fine but oh well...

Comment: What's better answer? IMHO, more detail in answer with full source code sample is better than another answers (with context, incomplete, etc). Anyways, if source code is 90% different, maybe be appropiate new answer.

Comment: @Kiquenet the point is the original one is an answer, the edited one is not. The OP deleted the answer and replaced it with another question/problem. That's not an answer...

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you completely disagree with the edit then roll it back to your last version. It is your answer (or question) and you should (by and large<sup>*</sup>) have the last word on what it looks like. The editor should honour this and leave the question alone.

If the editor rolls back your roll back an automatic flag will be raised and the mods can deal with it.

If the editor thinks your answer is wrong then they should be adding a new answer giving their  solution rather than modifying yours.

* Exceptions would include tags on questions, the formatting of code as code (i.e. each line preceded by four spaces), the syntax highlighting hints for code blocks.

Comment: Ok, thanks, just did my first roll-back!

Comment: This was about an answer, not a question.  I hesitated to edit :)

Comment: @HansPassant - oops. My mistake. The same argument applies though.

Comment: Interesting that edit-wars are automatically flagged.  I'll be a little more bold in reverting stuff in the future if I need to.

Comment: "you should have the last word on what it looks like" there are exceptions to this, like tags.

Comment: What if so called editor is a moderator? When OP rolls back to the original what if moderator votes it down? Recently I had a question on Seasonal Advice about substitutes for GMO flour. And this is moderator's justification for the edit: `My edits were for two primary things: fixing grammar and clarifying, and removing potentially
inflammatory statements about GMOs.` Even to date, we're unable to understand why & how a SE moderator decides which jargon to be inflammatory or not. Then he kept editing all my questions afterwards. This was my first encounter in SE, mainly because the word "GMO".